# How to rewrite path to url with semicolon in nginx?

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I am using nginx as a reverse proxy, a Angular Universal application is serving in the background.

I am trying to rewrite an old URL pattern to a new one via nginx, namely

```
server {
    rewrite ^/s/(.+)$ /search\;q=$1 permanent;`
    ...
}
```

such that something like `/s/keywords` gets redirected to `/search;q=keywords`

Unfortunately, the above nginx rule turns

`/s/keywords` into `/search/;q=keywords` (so a slash gets added after `/search`). Is there a chance to remove this slash so the result is `/search;q=keywords`?

(The application running behind nginx expects the url to be `/search;q=keywords`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add quotes to the replacement, for example:

```
rewrite ^/s/(.+)$ "/search;q=$1" permanent;
```